# how to know when to cancel asynctask when view becomes recycle in listview

Tags: java, android

in a listview the view gets recycled, therefore the asynctask(if it was called) will need ot be canceled. You can do this by calling: cancel(true);

But how do I know when the view gets recycled and therefore we need to cancel it's async thread ?

Comment: in `getView` you receive the view that is being recycled. that's when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a tag to every `imageview` that you want to download, for example if you want to download `imageview` at position 10 then set a tag in the `imageview` with a value of "10" and the object of `asynctask` that is responsible for downloading that `url`. now each time a new `imageview` you get(getview passes it to you) check the stored position in the tag, if it is the same with a value of the position in the `getview` it means that the `asynctask` that is inside the tag is downloading correct `url` and we are all happy, but if the stored position in the `imageview` is different from getview position, cancel the stored `asynctask` and create a new one and store this new one with a new position value in the tag of `imageview`. In this scenario you also have to store `imageview` reference as a `weakreference` in the `asynctask` so that when the downloading process is completed you have to set the image into the `imageview`. this is called `lazy loading`. In order to download less image from internet store your images in a `LRUCache`, so for each new request first check the cache then create new `asynctask`.

Comment: sorry but currently I do not have and also I do not think it is hard to create a test project and give it a try:-)

Answer (score 0):

Either check that `convertView` isn't null in the adapter's `getView`, or if you want to know when the view has been made available to be recycled:

```
ListView.setRecyclerListener(new OnRecyclerListener() {
    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
        // view is available to be recycled / been moved off screen
    }
});
```

Although, having the AsyncTask linked to the visibility of the view is probably a bad idea.